# Can a deliquent become a director in a Florida Condo?

Tags: florida

Florida Condo law is governed by Florida Statues 718.  Can a director candidate be eligible for office if they are 90 days delinquent for a nonpayment of late fee?  Given that there is a section that they can have the ([718.303 subsection 5](http://www.leg.state.fl.us/Statutes/index.cfm?App_mode=Display_Statute&URL=0700-0799/0718/Sections/0718.303.html)) voting right revoked, is there a similar rule that prevents them from holding office?

Comment: The statute doesn't seem to say much about the qualifications of board members. Do the bylaws say anything about that?

Comment: Could not find anything in the bylaws that says this.

Comment: Then probably anyone can be a director.  If people don't want a delinquent owner to be a director then they won't vote for that person.